# creating nested json file in node js

Tags: node.js, json

Here I want to create a nested json file. I have a variable `loggedPerson1` as string which takes `username` of the person who have logged in and that person selects the courses. I want to create the json file in such a manner that registered courses would come under that name of that user.

```
var exists = fs.existsSync('RegisteredCourses.json'); 
if(exists) {
    console.log("Loading");
    var data = fs.readFileSync('RegisteredCourses.json', 'utf-8');
    objRegister = JSON.parse(data);
}
else  {
    console.log('created new ')
    var objRegister = {loggedPerson1:[]};
}

app.get('/RegisteredCourses',(req,res) =>{

    res.send(loggedPerson)
})

app.post('/RegisteredCourses',(req,res) =>{
    var declaredCourse =
        {
        key: Date.now().toString(),
        CourseName : req.body.CourseName,

        CourseCode: req.body.CourseCode,
        StartDate:req.body.StartDate,
        EndDate:req.body.EndDate,
        Total_Fee: req.body.Fees,

        Delivery_Mode : req.body.Delivery_Mode,
        Description : req.body.Description,
        CourseType: req.body.CourseType
      }

         if(!declaredCourse.CourseName ){
            reply  ={
                msg:"Please enter data correctly"
            }
            res.send(reply)
        }
        else{
            objRegister.loggedPerson1.push(declaredCourse)

         let data = JSON.stringify(objRegister, null, 2);

         fs.writeFile('RegisteredCourses.json',data,finished);

         console.log('RegisteredCourses updated')
 
         function finished(err){
             reply = {
                 status:"Success",
                 
             }



             res.send(reply)
             console.log(reply)
         }



        }
})
```

Comment: Ok so what's not working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you're looking for the structure of the JSON here or something else. The JSON structure could be something like:

```
{
  "students": {
    "studentName": "Person 1",
    "Courses": {
      "one": "one",
      "two": "two"
    }
  }
}
```

your code to read it out with:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('RegisteredCourses.json', 'utf-8');
objRegister = JSON.parse(data);
```

should work fine, i've used the same in my projects.